# How do I subscribe to a custom event in a Vue directive?

Tags: vue.js, events, vue-directives

I want to build a vue directive that listens to custom events emitted by vue-components with `$emit` and then reacts to the event. Something like this:

```
<some-component v-my-custom-directive-on:click="someData">
...
</some-component>
```

Unfortunately I'm unsure how to do that. I tried using:

```
bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context.$on(binding.arg, data => { ... });
}
```

But the event handler is never called.

Any help?

Comment: I think you are confusing [custom events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) with [custom directives](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html). What are you trying to achive exactly? A custom click handler?

Comment: Not confusing anything. I want to subscribe to a "custom event" within a "custom directive". Imagine something like a logging/tracing helper. On selected components I want to attach a directive like: v-trace-on:click="Element was clicked". Directives seemed like a nice way to do this.

Comment: Still don't see why you need a custom directive for this. Look up `vue event bus` if you want a global event handler, but for logging only, the available tools are there (console.debug/log/error/dir/group, and vue devtools). Remember, storing and handling logs on client side is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that by using the "componentInstance"

e.g.

```
bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.componentInstance.$on('name of your emitted event', data => { ... });
}
```